# Intel Pin: How to generate objectdump-ish code?

Tags: c++, intel-pin

I am experimenting with intel-pin tool. I have a simple `Hello-world.c` (It prints nothing but "Hello world") program (say `a.out`). If I want to generate assembly from the binary, I would do `objdump -D a.out`.

I want to instrument some instructions in that.

Is it possible to get objdump using pin tool, before (This can be easily done by objdump) and after instrumentation?

I have created a tool which prints all the instructions.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "pin.H"
#include <cstdint>

FILE * trace;

KNOB<string> KnobOutputFile(KNOB_MODE_WRITEONCE, "pintool", "o", "pinatrace.out","A pin tool");

VOID Count(INS ins, void *v) {


        fprintf(trace,"\n%s",(INS_Disassemble(ins)).c_str());

}

VOID Fini(INT32 code, VOID *v)
{
        printf("count = %ld\n",(long)icount);
        fprintf(trace, "#eof\n");
        fclose(trace);
}

/* ===================================================================== */
/* Print Help Message                                                    */
/* ===================================================================== */

INT32 Usage()
{
    PIN_ERROR( "This Pintool prints a trace of memory addresses\n"
              + KNOB_BASE::StringKnobSummary() + "\n");
    return -1;
}

/* ===================================================================== */
/* Main                                                                  */
/* ===================================================================== */

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (PIN_Init(argc, argv)) return Usage();

    trace = fopen("pinatrace.out", "w");


    INS_AddInstrumentFunction(Count, 0);
    PIN_AddFiniFunction(Fini, 0);
    // Never returns
    PIN_StartProgram();

    return 0;
}
```

It prints the assembly instructions, but I am not sure if it includes the instrumented instructions.

Is this the proper way to do this? Could you please help me?

Comment: PIN is meant to be transparent; you can think of the code after instrumentation to be identical to before instrumentation (of course the actual code is nothing like before instrumentation, but that's PIN's implementation details and is pure magic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to get objdump using pin tool, before (This can be easily done by objdump) and after instrumentation?

You'll need a way to tell the PIN engine what you want to do with the results from objdump.  You might want to link both of them though a script for example. It totally depends on what you want to do though.

> Is this the proper way to do this?

Depends on what you want to do exactly, but I guess it's not.

There's a clear distinction between **instrumentation** and **analysis** in PIN. Once you understand it, the rest is (relatively) easy.

Conceptually, PIN instrumentation consists of two components:

- A mechanism that decides where and what code is inserted: the **instrumentation**.
- The code to execute at insertion points: the **analysis**.

That being said, one more important point:

- The instrumentation is only run **once**: when the instruction (or BBL, or TRACE) is discovered for the first time.
- The analysis is run **each time** the instruction (or BBL, TRACE) is executed.

---

So when you have:

```
// set up the **instrumentation**
INS_AddInstrumentFunction(Func_Instrumentation, 0);
```

You are setting up the instrumentation (which is then only called once). If you need a callback to be called each time an instruction (or BBL, TRACE) is executed you need to set up an analysis routine, for example:

```
// this is the **analysis** routine.
// This function is called before every instruction is executed
VOID docount() { icount++; }

// The is the **instrumentation routine**, called by INS_AddInstrumentFunction().
// Pin calls this function each time a **new** instruction is encountered
// Note that is won't be called for the same instruction after the first time.
VOID Func_Instrumentation(INS ins, VOID *v)
{
    // Insert a call to docount before every instruction, no arguments are passed
    INS_InsertCall(
        ins,              // a representation of the instruction
        IPOINT_BEFORE,    // where to insert, relative to the instruction
        (AFUNPTR)docount, // the analysis routine
        IARG_END);        // no args to pass to the analysis routine
}
```

Check carefully the instruction count sample available:

- In `source/tools/ManualExamples/inscount0.cpp`
- [In the PIN Manual](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/pintool/docs/97619/Pin/html/index.html#SimpleCount)

Comment: Very well explained. Let's say I want to add some instructions to the assembly,  regardless of what I want to do. For eg. I want to add a mov r1,r2 (just an example) in the assembly. Is there any way to verify my code is working with those added instructions? (forgive me if I'm wrong, I'm just a beginner)

Comment: @Ruturaj Not sure if you want to add those new instructions with PIN (it's possible although not very easy) or just add them in your source, compile and then check if they are executed with PIN. It also depends on what you are expecting by "verify my code is working" but simply verifying that the execution is the one intended falls under what PIN is able to do.

Comment: yes, I want to add those new instructions with PIN, but not in my source code.

Comment: I finally designed it taking your considerations into account. I think your answer helped me with that, so marking it as a correct answer.